# Matrix algebra properties square of $Ax-b$

Tags: matrices, least-squares

I have seen the least squares formula derived like this :

$f(x) = ||Ax-b||_2^2 = \\
(Ax-b)^2 =\\
x^TA^TAx-2b^TAx+b^Tb\\
\nabla f(x) = 2A^TAx -2Ab = 0 => x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$

I'm trying to derive this myself, but I cant figure out one part from these matrix algebra properties:

$(Ax-b)^2 = (Ax-b)^T(Ax-b) = \\
(Ax-b)^TAx - (Ax-b)^Tb = \\
((Ax)^T-b^T)Ax - ((Ax)^T-b^T)b = \\
(Ax)^TAx - b^TAx -(Ax)^Tb + b^Tb = \\
x^TA^TAx - b^TAx - x^TA^Tb + b^Tb
$

What matrix properties do I need to get : $b^TAx - x^TA^Tb = 2b^TAx$ ?

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$(Ax-b)^T\,(Ax-b) = \sum_i  (\sum_j A_{ij}x_j - b_i)^2\,,
$$
so taking the derivative of the above w.r.t. $x_k$ and setting equal to $0$ we have
$$
0 = \sum_i  2(\sum_j A_{ij}x_j - b_i)(\sum_j A_{ij}\delta_{jk}) = \sum_i 2(\sum_j A_{ij}x_j-b_i)A_{ik} = (A^TAx-A^Tb)_k\,,
$$
i.e.
$$
x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T b\,.
$$

Comment: But why does $A$ have to be symmetric, if we are talking least-squares it would be a matrix whose rows are different samples, so that would not be symmetric right?

Comment: @Frank you actually yeah you're right, I think your source might be dodgy with the details. I'll add the proper derivation.